# How to Disable Screen Rotation Icon

Tags: 9.0-pie, samsung-galaxy-s-9

I lock my screen rotation to portrait, and I have my navigation bar hidden to provide more screen real estate.

With the navigation bar hidden, I have come to experience the rotation icon appear in the bottom right corner just above the virtual keyboard enter/submit key. As it would typically be displayed in the navigation bar, it has its separate icon when it is hidden.

This is a problem because even when the icon is invisible, it blocks the touch to the vk key, albeit a tiny sliver of the edge still able to be pressed.

Is there a way that I can retain the hidden navigation bar and disable the rotation icon?

Additional information: My phone is stock, not rooted.

**Edit**

As of software update G965FXXU2CSB3/G965FOXM2CSB3/G965FXXU2CSB3, this is no longer an issue. However, I would still like to know how to disable the icon from appearing.

[image: IMG:]

Comment: On LineageOS (Android 11) the icon looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qQqq1.png ([developer response](https://teddit.net/r/LineageOS/comments/n8020k/lineageos_18_how_to_remove_bottom_left_corner/))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is indeed a way to disable it by ADB.

- Setup ADB on your PC/Mac.
- Enable USB debugging on your android
- Connect your device to the PC/Mac
- Run following command in shell/terminal:

> adb shell settings put secure show_rotation_suggestions 0

Comment: You, sir or madam, are fantastic. Thank you very much, this indeed worked.

Comment: The command still works on Android 11. Thank you. I hated that little obnoxious button with passion.

Answer (score 9):

Or you could do it the easy way.... I just figured it out with a lightbulb moment turning my flashlight brightness down

[image]
[image]

Comment: I have not tried this method yet, but it does seem like it would work, thank you. This saves having to use adb for average users.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually this icon disturbing me from 6 months while typing on SwiftKey.

Comment: Thank you.!!! I was bothered by this for an year

Comment: Probably, it is a Samsung-only thing. On other Androids I have tested, clicking that button just toggles auto-rotationbon/off, and long-pressing it just opens the Display settings.

Answer (score -1):

Unless Google or Samsung bring out an update to give you the option to disable it, the icon can't be disabled.

Comment: How did you reach this bold conclusion?

Comment: This is a feature Google created in Android 9 and didn't add an option to disable it. CodeMonkey's phone is running completely stock so unless the phone is rooted there is no way to disable the icon. Even if the phone is rooted there is no guarantee that this can be disabled depending on how deep this function is built in to Android.

Comment: Well somebody disagrees with you (https://android.stackexchange.com/a/212608/166631). P.S. His solution works.